How can I arrange my bibliography in alphabetical order?
Kindly help me. I want to arrange my bibliography list alphabetically. I really need someone's help because I have been stuck on this task for a long time.
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{plain} 
    \bibliography{allref}
\end{document}

Following is the list of some references.
@book{chhabra2011non,
  title={Non-Newtonian flow and applied rheology: engineering applications},
  author={Chhabra, R. and Richardson, J.},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Butterworth-Heinemann}
}

@article{eringen1964simple,
  title={Simple microfluids},
  author={Eringen, A.},
  journal={International Journal of Engineering Science},
  volume={2},
  pages={205--217},
  year={1964}
}

@article{cowin1968polar,
  title={Polar fluids},
  author={Cowin, S.},
  journal={The Physics of Fluids},
  volume={11},
  pages={1919--1927},
  year={1968}
}

@article{maugin1983internal,
  title={Internal variables and the thermodynamics of macromolecule solutions},
  author={Maugin, G. and Drouot, R.},
  journal={International Journal of Engineering Science},
  volume={21},
  pages={705--724},
  year={1983}
}

 @article{rees1998free,
  title={Free convection boundary-layer flow of a micropolar fluid from a vertical flat plate},
  author={Rees, D. and Pop, I.},
  journal={IMA Journal of Applied Mathematics},
  volume={61},
  pages={179--197},
  year={1998}
}

@article{srinivasacharya2010heat,
  title={Heat and mass transfer by natural convection in a doubly stratified non-Darcy micropolar fluid},
  author={Srinivasacharya, D. and RamReddy, C.},
  journal={International Communications in Heat and Mass Transfer},
  volume={37},
  pages={873--880},
  year={2010}
}

@article{mishra2015effect,
  title={Effect of heat source and double stratification on MHD free convection in a micropolar fluid},
  author={Mishra, S. and Pattnaik, P. and Dash, G.},
  journal={Alexandria Engineering Journal},
  volume={54},
  pages={681--689},
  year={2015}
}

@article{magyari2011double,
  title={Double-diffusive natural convection flows with thermosolutal symmetry in porous media in the presence of the Soret--Dufour effects},
  author={Magyari, E. and Postelnicu, A.},
  journal={Transport in Porous Media},
  volume={88},
  pages={149--167},
  year={2011}
}


if you are using natbib you probably should be using its version {plainnat} not {plain} bibliography style

Off-topic: (a) The geometry option list top=0.6 in,bottom=0.6 in,left=0.6 in,right=0.6 in may be expressed more compactly as margin=0.6in. (b) The amssymb package loads the amsfonts package automatically; hence, no need to load amsfonts separately.

@DavidCarlisle - Both plain and plainnat are programmed to sort bibliographic entries alphatically by authors' surnames.

@Mico yes of course but there were incompatibilities between plain and natbib in some cases which is why natbib comes with its own versions of all the standard bibtex styles hence plainnat, so even if plain happens to work, plainnat would be better with natbib

I would recommend using JabRef (https://www.jabref.org/) - it allows you to import a list of references, a .bib file, and allows for sorting, etc.. afterwards it generates a new list of references for you in your preferred order, as a .bib that you can use as is within your document.

@simply_a_student But doesn't LaTeX resort your references based on the \bibliography style that you use?

I guess the style chosen could re-sort it in some cases, @Teepeemm, but for the MWE the style chosen was 'plain', so the JabRef solution should work without any additional workaround required? I do not really know enough about the various styles, and their inner workings, to know what they do.  Either way, it makes for a nice interface to work with the bibliography when using JabRef.

@simply_a_student - The OP's issue is not whether the bibliographic entries are sorted alphabetically in the bib file (something that JabRef can do something about). The OP's issue is how to get the entries sorted alphabetically in the typeset output -- something that JabRef has no influence on.

The plain bibliography style, which has been around more or less unchanged since the mid to late 1980s, is one of the original BibTeX bibliography style files. It sorts all bibliographic entries alphabetically by authors' surnames. The fact that this does not appear to be the case for your bibliography is, frankly, rather puzzling. All I can surmise is that you (a) have been using a different bibliography style -- possibly unsrt -- until recently and (b) have failed to re-run BibTeX after changing from \bibliographstyle{unsrt} to \bibliographystyle{plain}. Do please provide more information about your document setup.
Some additional comments regarding your LaTeX and BibTeX code are in order:

By default, plain and many other bibliography styles apply "sentence style" to the contents of fields such as title for many entry types, including the @article entry type. This means that for entries of type @article, all words in the title field (except those at the very start of the field) are automatically converted to all-lowercase unless they are "protected" by encasing them in curly braces.
For the magyari2011double, mishra2015effect, and srinivasacharya2010heat entries, respectively, you need to protect the strings "Soret--Dufour", "MHD", and "non-Darcy", by encasing them in curly braces.

The newly-protected string "{Soret}--{Dufour}" could employ a simple dash character instead of an endash, i.e., it could be written as "{Soret}-{Dufour}". However, I've been made aware that there are arguments to keep the endash spelling, i.e., "{Soret}--{Dufour}". (Thanks, @DrM!)

The publisher field in the chhabra2011non entry doesn't look right; for sure, online sources say that Elsevier is the publisher of the 2011 piece. Also, don't needlessly lowercase words in the title field, as you're dealing with an entry of type @book.

Since you employ the natbib citation management package, you might as well employ the plainnat bibliography style instead of plain. There are at least two advantages to using plainnat: (a) It recognizes additional fields, such as url, doi, and eid, which are commonplace nowadays but were unknown in the 1980s. (b) It lets you switch from numeric-style citation callouts to authoryear-style citation callouts simply by changing the package option numbers to authoryear, i.e., there's no need to re-run BibTeX to change the citation callout style. In contrast, the plain style can only generate numeric-style citation callouts; if you ever have to switch to generating authoryear-style citation callouts, you'd have to both change the argument of \bibliographystyle and rerun BibTeX.




\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% create a bib file "on the fly"
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@book{chhabra2011non,
  title={Non-Newtonian Flow and Applied Rheology: Engineering Applications},
  author={Chhabra, R. P. and Richardson, J. F.},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{eringen1964simple,
  title={Simple microfluids},
  author={Eringen, A.},
  journal={International Journal of Engineering Science},
  volume={2},
  pages={205--217},
  year={1964}
}

@article{cowin1968polar,
  title={Polar fluids},
  author={Cowin, S.},
  journal={The Physics of Fluids},
  volume={11},
  pages={1919--1927},
  year={1968}
}

@article{maugin1983internal,
  title={Internal variables and the thermodynamics of macromolecule solutions},
  author={Maugin, G. and Drouot, R.},
  journal={International Journal of Engineering Science},
  volume={21},
  pages={705--724},
  year={1983}
}

@article{rees1998free,
  title={Free convection boundary-layer flow of a micropolar fluid from a vertical flat plate},
  author={Rees, D. and Pop, I.},
  journal={IMA Journal of Applied Mathematics},
  volume={61},
  pages={179--197},
  year={1998}
}

@article{srinivasacharya2010heat,
  title={Heat and mass transfer by natural convection in a doubly stratified {non-Darcy} micropolar fluid},
  author={Srinivasacharya, D. and RamReddy, C.},
  journal={International Communications in Heat and Mass Transfer},
  volume={37},
  pages={873--880},
  year={2010}
}

@article{mishra2015effect,
  title={Effect of heat source and double stratification on {MHD} free convection in a micropolar fluid},
  author={Mishra, S. and Pattnaik, P. and Dash, G.},
  journal={Alexandria Engineering Journal},
  volume={54},
  pages={681--689},
  year={2015}
}

@article{magyari2011double,
  title={Double-diffusive natural convection flows with thermosolutal symmetry in porous media in the presence of the {Soret-Dufour} effects},
  author={Magyari, E. and Postelnicu, A.},
  journal={Transport in Porous Media},
  volume={88},
  pages={149--167},
  year={2011}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.6in]{geometry}
%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain} % better: 'plainnat'

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\setstretch{1} % revert to single-spacing
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}


as per your comments my document setup is already mentioned in MWE, my bib file contains more than 200 references. Each and every reference had obtained from the Google scholar. Additionally I have been trying to incorporate the given suggestions. Once I get any update in the direction of answer surely I will paste it here.

@SandyM - Thanks. Please also indicate whether you've recently changed the argument of \bibliographystyle and, if so, if you've re-run BibTeX since then.

"The newly-protected string "{Soret}--{Dufour}" should employ a simple dash character instead of an endash, i.e., it should be written as "{Soret}-{Dufour}""
Why do you say this? Many style guides prefer use of the endash to distinguish two separate names (as in this case) from a single double-barrelled surname.

@DrM - I'm aware that some (many??) style guides suggest using an en-dash in this situation, but I believe that such advice is somewhat misguided. For sure, I don't understand the need to "distinguish two separate names from a single double-barreled surname". Is anyone going to infer that the spelling "Bose-Einstein condensate", with a single - character, implies that Satyendra Bose and Albert Einstein got together and formed an inter-person union? (I hope not...) However, given that there's some variation in practice, I'll reformulate the piece of advice as a recommendation.
